# Android: How to resize BackgroundDrawable for a Linear Layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have to set a BackgorundDrawbale for a LinearLayout. The BackgroundDrawable has a greater height than the LinearLayout and ignores the defined height in the XML Layout (besides i don't want to use an absolute height but "wrap_content")  - and therefore increases the height of the Layout. Is there a way to scale the Drawable dynamically that it doesn't increase the height? - Or do I have to Crop the Drawable e.g in Photoshop to the right height? - There must be another way.

I already wrapped my head around similar questions on StackOverflow which use the RelativeLayout. But I didn't get the desired result.

My Layout looks like the following, it is used in a ListView for the first row. The Layout should end below the image - but it doesn't because of the Drawable.

[image: ListView LinearLayout at first row]

Currently I am using the following XML Layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/foto_detail_bg_cell_0"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"

            />

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:textSize="14dip"

                />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip"
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:textSize="14dip"

                />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would be glad for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i made the background image smaller than the height of the layout. Now it gets scaled (stretched) automatically to the right size.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find any alternative either

Answer (score 0):

Use a single Relative layout and fixed with wrap content both for height and width. Code which is working fine for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and where do i put the line `android:background="@drawable/foto_detail_bg_cell_0"`?